# Unable to build RTAB map using 2d rotating LiDAR

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, 3d-slam, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using a rotating 2d lidar and then using laser assembler package to get 3d point cloud.
[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N-_6aOX9tfVqujODFiRhJ41kamHjVGpZ/view?usp=sharing)

I can see the point cloud but when I used in RTAB no map frame is generated neither it is able to map the data.
Here is my launch file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <launch>
      <!-- Mapping -->
      <group ns="rtabmap">
    
    <node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap">
       <param name="subscribe_depth"      type="bool"   value="false"/>
       <param name="subscribe_rgb"        type="bool"   value="false"/>
       <param name="subscribe_scan_cloud" type="bool"   value="true"/>
    
       <remap from="scan_cloud" to="/laser_pointcloud"/> <!-- sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 -->
       <remap from="odom"       to="/odom"/> <!-- odometry from wheel encoders + IMU fusion -->

      <!-- output -->
   <remap from="grid_map" to="/map"/>
    
    </node>
 <!-- <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"  args="-d $(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/config/turtlebot_navigation.rviz"/> -->    
  </group>
</launch>
```

I'm not sure if it is because of the rotating laser transform to the base link is being received properly or not. You can see the tf tree as no map frame is published [Frames](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15615774462276194.png)

Can anyone help me?
[image: Warning]

[Updated]
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327070/unable-to-build-rtab-map-using-2d-rotating-lidar/) by [tsdk00](https://answers.ros.org/users/37919/tsdk00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2019-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-06-27**:
If `/map -> /odom` frame is not published, it means rtabmap is not started because it didn't receive topics yet. Do you have warnings on terminal if you set `<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap" output="screen">`?

**Comment by [tsdk00](https://answers.ros.org/users/37919/tsdk00/) on 2019-06-27**:
@matlabbe
Here is the Warning message as updated above

You can also look at my bag file. The issue what I think is since it is doing a vertical scan so it is not getting enough point cloud data to produce the 3d map. So eventually some accumulated laser scan has to be provided.
I tried the same bag file with cartographer and there is a parameter in Cartographer to provide accumulated laser scan data. So when I set it to 40, I can get a 3d map.
[BAG](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XErV8R6uDOVjt2QIvP6WTKjb33kn_Yll/view?usp=sharing)

**Comment by [tsdk00](https://answers.ros.org/users/37919/tsdk00/) on 2019-06-29**:
Thanks for your reply. Yeah, it works.No more warnings. Just wanted to know would it be ideal to  make the /laser_pointcloud and /odom published at the same rate? I updated the rate figure above and changed the queue_size to 50.

```
rosrun rtabmap_ros rtabmap -d _subscribe_depth:=false _subscribe_rgb:=false _subscribe_scan_cloud:=true scan_cloud:=/laser_pointcloud odom:=/odom  _approx_sync:=true _queue_size:=50
```

And just last question, which point_cloud data in rviz you subscribed to get that map. I mean there are many point_cloud data and I'm getting this as updated above in the main question.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-07-02**:
You could have kept it to 500Hz, but more time/memory would be used to manage the synchronization queue. My concern is if the queue could eventually have 500 scans at the same time, not sure if [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters/ApproximateTime) discard automatically older scan msgs if all 500 of odom are more recent. Maybe it is negligible too. Another way is to subscribe to TF for odometry instead, with `_odom_frame_id:="odom" _odom_tf_angular_variance:=0.0005 _odom_tf_angular_variance:=0.0001`

For your last question, you seem using `cloud_map` topic, which is voxelized at 5 cm by default. I was showing the one built from `rtabmap_ros/MapCloud` rviz plugin (available only with latest version and check "Cloud from scan" checkbox).

**Comment by [tsdk00](https://answers.ros.org/users/37919/tsdk00/) on 2019-07-02**:
Yeah, will try. But the plots look eventually fine. Thanx a lot for your help

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2021-06-10**:
Hi, @tsdk00 could you send me your bag file? (it's not downloadable now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, thx for the bag. The `/odom` tropic is published at >500Hz and `/laser_pointcloud` is 1 Hz. The `queue_size` should be then around 500! `approx_sync` should be also true (false in your warning saying exact sync is used). The TF `/odom -> /base_link` seems to give a lot of `Detected jump back in time of 0.000423494s. Clearing TF buffer.` warnings. You could decrease odometry frame rate to 50 Hz or 20 Hz. With the following, I am still able to have a map:

```
$ roscore
$ rosparam set use_sim_time true
$ rosbag play --clock rotating_lidar_straight_pipe.bag
$ rosrun rtabmap_ros rtabmap -d _subscribe_depth:=false _subscribe_rgb:=false _subscribe_scan_cloud:=true scan_cloud:=/laser_pointcloud odom:=/odom  _approx_sync:=true _queue_size:=500
```

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1